# Cloudflare SSL not working - Showing as insecure site

Tags: ssl, heroku, cloudflare

<--------- Update ---------->

So I tried using digicert instead of SSL Labs and this is what I got. This is why my ssl isn't working properly with CloudFlare and Heroku.

[image]

<--------------------------->

For some reason, my CloudFlare SSL isn't working properly and I continuously get this error. Really lost and could use some help. Below are screenshots of the error and my CloudFlare Crypto Settings.

[image: The error message]

[image: Crypto Settings 1]

[image: Crypto Settings 2]

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue here. Turns out it was a simple fix. All you have to do on CloudFlare is make sure the subdomains e.g. www are routed through cloudflare as well instead of through the primary host e.g. heroku.

You can do this by clicking on the cloud next do you CNAME record and making sure it's orange.

I also recommend using [www.digicert.com](http://www.digicert.com) instead of [www.ssllabs.com](http://www.ssllabs.com) because you get a lot more helpful information.

[image]

Cheers,

Comment: There is a CloudFlare Help Centre article that you might find useful - What subdomains are appropriate for orange / gray clouds? https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169626-What-subdomains-are-appropriate-for-orange-gray-clouds-

Comment: @mjsa thank you for that! I've put it in my notebook for next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an SSL testing tool like https://www.digicert.com/help/ or https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html ? They might help narrow down where the problem may be.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried ssllabs and:

domain.com works, www.domain.com doesn't work 

On CloudFlare it said that first level subdomains are covered with wildcards as well so I'm not sure why www.domain.com doesn't work

Comment: Hey David, I have just posted the results I get from digicert. Would you be able to take a look at the heroku certificate clashing with the CloudFlare one? thank you!

Comment: Hey @ClementOh, I'm pleased these links were helpful. In the future you'll probably find both are useful, it depends what you are troubleshooting or trying to verify.